# How to make 2 AD tenants authenticate between each other?

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I am a service provider which develops PBI reports to multiple clients.
I manage the PBI account and tenants for my clients. For each client I create a new tenant which I manage for them. In this tenants I keep all the PBI fils (PBIX), reports and datasets.
If my client already has a 365 account (for his email, teams etc) I create a new tenant in addition to the one he uses.

For example: the client private tenant is @ABCcompany.com. in this tenant, the client has his email account, teams, Office 365 etc.
I create a tenant @**BI**ABCcompany. This tenant stores the PBI account.

In the current situation, shen the client wants to use the BI reports , he need to log out of his private 365 tenant (@ABCcompany.com) and log in to (**BI**ABCcompany.com).

My final goals are:

- I want to remove this sign in and sign out step, but I don’t want to
  store the PBI files (PBIX) files on the client tenants.
- I want that my client will be able to consume the PBI reports on
  Microsoft teams while he signing to his tenants (@ABCcompany.com)

As I imagine this, I need to make both tenants to talk to teach other and be able to aunticate between one to each other?
I this possible?

What I need to do? I read about guests accounts, share domain and many other Azure AD feature but I don;t sure which one of them I should use.

Thank you, Tal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can make use of Azure AD B2B collaboration to achieve your scenario.***

> **[Azure AD B2B collaboration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b)  enables users to use one set of credentials to sign in to multiple  tenants.**

Using the above method, the user with **`@ABCcompany.com`** can be invited as a **guest user** to another tenant (`@BIABCcompany.com`) and he can sign in using his home tenant credentials(`@ABCcompany.com`).

***You can create the guest users by referring this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-add-azure-active-directory-b2b-collaboration-users-in-the-azure-portal/) of Hadshana Kamalanathan like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> New user*

[image]

***To make the guest users to access the resources in another tenant, make sure to modify the settings like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> External Identities -> External collaboration settings*

[image]

**References:**

[Multi-tenant architecture for large institutions - M365 Education | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-multi-tenant-architecture#collaborate-across-tenants-using-azure-ad-b2b-collaboration)

[Enable B2B external collaboration settings - Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/external-collaboration-settings-configure)